# fastest way of getting an array of references from object keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have a global object that looks like this:

```
var TheFruits = {

   323: {},
   463: {},
   223: {} ..... // can be thousands of properties
}
```

Basically, the keys are IDs and the values are themselves objects. Now suppose I have an array of IDs that I pass into a function and I want that function to return an array of references to the values that match the IDs of the global object (ie. no deep copy). Something like this:

```
function GetReferences(TheArrayOfIDs) {

   var TheArrayOfReferences = [];

   return TheArrayOfReferences;
}
```

Now I know I can write a for loop that iterates over TheArrayOfIDs and that then loops over the object keys at each iteration but then that's a loop within a loop. So I'm looking for the fastest way of doing it, and jquery is available.

Basically, if `TheArrayOfIDs = [323, 463, 223];`  then `TheArrayOfReferences =[TheFruit.323, TheFruit.463, TheFruit.223];`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a second loop:

```
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
    results.push(fruits[ids[i]]);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer; no need for the second loop. Upvoted and accepted because of native javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do only one loop as key look-up is built-in :

```
var TheArrayOfReferences = TheArrayOfIDs.map(function(id){return TheFruits[id]});
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer; no need for the second loop. Upvoted: I love jquery too.

Comment: Note that I don't use jQuery. This is pure native javascript. JavaScript is awesome.

Comment: ah I see: what's the difference in terms of perf with SLaks's answer?

Comment: Both will run at about the same speed. Don't bother with premature optimization : try to optimize when you find and locate a performance  problem and it won't be here. Choose the most readable solution.

Comment: Not about perf, but this uses [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which is implemented since ECMAScript 5 and therefore not supported by all Browsers -> < IE 9

Comment: +1 Yes, this is true. If you want to be compatible with IE8 and still use the map/filter/forEach facilities, you need a shim (see example of such a shim in @C5H8NNaO4 's link. Personally I prefer the functional way but there is absolutely no problem with slaks answer.

Comment: Ohhhh, then I definitely (unfortunately) need IE8 support!!

Answer (score 1):

Something like that should work :

```
var i = 0, l = TheArrayOfIDs.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
    TheArrayOfReferences.push(TheFruits[TheArrayOfIDs[i]]);
```

Comment: It should be `.push(TheFruits[TheArrayOfIds[i]])`